# Thus Vs This way

Tags: phrase-choice

Suppose someone does something which sounds strange for you. You ask them about the reason behind their action. Then they want to make you understand that what they did, had not been based on their decision, but the conditions necessitated that action to be taken. I would be thankful if you let me know how shall I complete my sentences in the most natural way:

> - The conditions necessitated **thus**.
> - The conditions necessitated **this way**.

- [Thus](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/thus) in the manner now being indicated or exemplified; **in this way**.
  Based on dictionaries' definitions, "thus" is exactly one of the best options to use instead of "in this way". We say it in this way in our language, but I doubt this is how you would say it in English.

But for the second sentence, my first question is that if the sentence I made is the way that a native would say it, and if yes, the preposition "in" is required or it can be missed.

The self-made sentences above are the only idiomatic ways to say that in my opinion.

Comment: The most natural way I can think of to answer such a scenario would be;  _The situation (or circumstances) called for it._  If you want to keep your original wording then; _The conditions necessitated it thus._

Comment: I doubt either would be used as written. You need to add more regarding why you want to use *thus* or *this way*. If you are asking for a rewrite, that is proofreading and there are lots of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of them sound idiomatic to this American English speaker.  [**Thus** is an adverb means, roughly, "in this way" or "because of this".](https://painintheenglish.com/case/4452/)  You certainly wouldn't say "The conditions necessitated *in this way*." or "The conditions necessitated *because of this*."

"The conditions necessitated this way" is slightly better, but it still doesn't sound completely fluent or idiomatic.  It makes some sense if we interpret "this way" as meaning "this particular course of doing things", but the problem is that *this way* sounds like an adverbial phrase meaning "in this manner", and so  *verb* + "this way" sounds like *verb in this manner*.  (For example, "talked this way" = "talked in this manner".)  You don't necessitate *in this manner*, you necessitate *a thing*, so "this way" sounds ambiguous and strange.

The most idiomatic way to phrase it would probably just be to say

> The conditions necessitated **it**.

or perhaps

> The conditions necessitated **these actions**.

if you want to be more specific.

*Necessitated* is a pretty high-flown, formal kind of word, though; it would be more common to say "required" or "called for" or "demanded".

Comment: If you're going to downvote an answer, could you explain why?  Downvotes with no explanation don't help anybody improve.